# Accumulate values in raster cells with backlink connectivity

Tags: raster, cost-path, calculate-values, least-cost, accumulated

[image]I have origin points in different regions and within these region also specific values within raster cells (with 50m resolution).
My goal is to sum up the values of all previous cells in the respective cells that are traversed.
And for example with Least Cost Path i can create a Backlink Raster, which shows me the movement.

But when I use the Least Cost Path tool, the respective values are extended by the grid cell size.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be used to accumulate only the actual values without the grid size?

Comment: It is not totally clear to me whether you are making reference to ArcGIS or to another specific software. Besides that, I am wondering if you want to calculate accumulated cost around multiple origin? Maybe, showing some images and/or providing an executable example would help other users here to help you out.

Comment: Primarily I am working with ArcGis.
And yes I have multiple origins. But like with LCP it calcualtes backlinks to the closest location. 
So my goal is to find a solution like LCP, but without adding the raster cell sizes when sum up all cell values the path went through.

Comment: @NewAtGis
I don't know if a screenshot is that helpful. Black cells are the origins, to all other cells the lowest value of a route to the origin should be calculated.